# Borel $\sigma$-algebra of subset of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I've tried to prove the following for several hours now but struggle to finish it (maybe it is super obvious/easy, but I don't have the right thoughts):

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal T)$ be a topological space, $\Omega' \in \sigma(\mathcal T, \Omega) = \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$ and $\mathcal T'$ the subspace topology on $\Omega'$ with respect to $\mathcal T$. Show that $$\mathcal B(\Omega', \mathcal T') = \{A\in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T) \, | \, A \subseteq \Omega' \}.$$

I've tried to do this in two directions. I have an ansatz for each direction:
$"\subseteq"$: We have to show that $A\in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$, i.e. for all $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal A$ over $\Omega$ with $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal A$ it holds that $A\in \mathcal A$. So let $\mathcal A$ be an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal A$. Because $\Omega' \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$ we have that $\Omega' \in \mathcal A$.
  Since $A \in \mathcal B(\Omega', \mathcal T')$ ...

and here's basically where I'm stuck. I don't know how to make the connection between
 $\mathcal A$ being a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ and "shrinking" it to one over just $\Omega'$. Same problem in the other direction. I feel like I need to use the definition of the subspace topology but don't really know how.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: The statement is wrong as stated. The correct one is $B(\Omega', \mathcal{T}') = \{A \cap \Omega': A \in B(\Omega, \mathcal{T})\}$.

Comment: This is taken from Analysis lecture notes my professor has used for several years. It might be false, but I doubt it. I think that this is in fact the difference between the subspace topology and the "subspace Borel $\sigma$-algebra."

Comment: my statement is true but reduces to yours because $\Omega' \in B(\Omega, \mathcal{T})$ ; My statement holds for any subset \Omega'$

Comment: Your statement is wrong as stated, you should modify it as @HennoBrandsma suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *any* subset $\Omega'$ it's fairly easy to see that

$$\mathcal B(\Omega', \mathcal T') = \{ A \cap \Omega': A \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)\}$$

Proof: the right hand side is clearly a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega'$ and it contains all of $\mathcal{T}'$ as all subspace open sets are of the form $O \cap \Omega'$ with $O \in \mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$, so by minimality we have the left to right inclusion. 
On the other hand, $i: \Omega' \rightarrow \Omega ,i(x) = x$ is continuous so for any Borel set $A$ of $\Omega$, $i^{-1}[A] = \Omega' \cap A$ is Borel in $\Omega'$ so the reverse inclusion also holds.

As an alternative to the last inclusion function argument:
let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ such that $A \cap \Omega'$ is Borel in $\Omega'$. One checks easily that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and it contains $\mathcal{T}$by the definition of a subspace topology. So $\mathcal{B}(\Omega, \mathcal{T}) \subset \mathcal{S}$ by minimality ,and this means exactly that the right to left inclusion holds, if you think about it.

From this general fact, yours follows (we now use $\Omega' \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$, because then:

$$\{ A \cap \Omega': A \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)\} = \{A \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T): A \subset \Omega' \}$$

(left to right: $A \cap \Omega'$ is indeed a subset of $\Omega'$ that is Borel as $\Omega'$ is and $A$ is. right to left is trivial as $A \subset \Omega'$ means that $A \cap \Omega' = A$, so the same $A$ works.)

Comment: Thank you, the inclusion map was the tool I needed for my proof.

Comment: @lappen68 For me the easiest way to see that the intersection of a Borel set in the large space with a subspace is Borel in the subspace

Comment: @lappen68 I gave a rather simple alternative argument as well.

Comment: Additional question: I struggle "easily" seeing that the right hand side is a $\sigma$-algebra. Taking complements gives $\Omega' \backslash (A\cap \Omega') = \Omega' \backslash A = \Omega' \backslash A \cap \Omega'$ but this only works if $\Omega' \in \mathcal B(\Omega, \mathcal T)$ right?

Comment: I claimed $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, so if $A \in \mathcal{S}$ then $A$ is such that $A \cap \Omega'$ is Borel in $\Omega'$, and then $(\Omega \setminus A) \cap \Omega' = \Omega' \setminus (\Omega' \cap A)$ so also Borel in $\Omega'$ , hence $\Omega\setminus A \in \mathcal{S}$ too. Similarly for other operations.

Comment: This would seem to generalize to any sigma algebra with a generating set.

Comment: @TomCollinge I use nothing special about open sets, so it could probably be stated more generally.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, prove that $\{A\in\mathcal B(\Omega,\mathcal T)\mid A\subseteq\Omega'\}$ is in fact a $\sigma$-algebra. This is not hard at all.

Secondly, show that every open set in $\cal T'$ lies in that $\sigma$-algebra, and that it is in fact Borel in $\cal T$. Together, this would give you the needed equality.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. So I guess my approach is not the best in this case.

Comment: This is a mild change from your approach, which makes it slightly easier to prove this statement. You can still work this with your approach, but I think it will be tantamount to just proving my suggestion and some more "around it".